# matplotlib pcolor not working when used as "2D plot in 3D"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a pcolor plot to the example code given here http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/2dcollections3d_demo.html

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi) / 2 + 0.5
ax.plot(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='zs=0, zdir=z')

colors = ('r', 'g', 'b', 'k')
for c in colors:
    x = np.random.sample(20)
    y = np.random.sample(20)
    ax.scatter(x, y, 0, zdir='y', c=c)

xc = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
yc = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fc = np.random.random((len(xc),len(yc)))
ax.pcolor(xc,yc,fc, zdir = 'x')

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

Just few new lines when compared to the original script. Unfortunately, it doesn't end well and I really don't understand why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 271, in draw
    for col in self.collections]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 271, in <listcomp>
    for col in self.collections]
AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'
```

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to achieve. There is a 3D plot in the example but `pcolor` is a 2D plot. You can't add a `pcolor` plot to the 3D plot, that's why you get the error, so add a new figure:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi) / 2 + 0.5
ax.plot(x, y, zs=0, zdir='z', label='zs=0, zdir=z')

colors = ('r', 'g', 'b', 'k')
for c in colors:
    x = np.random.sample(20)
    y = np.random.sample(20)
    ax.scatter(x, y, 0, zdir='y', c=c)

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)


fig = plt.figure()
xc = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
yc = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fc = np.random.random((len(xc),len(yc)))
plt.pcolor(xc,yc,fc,cmap='RdBu')
plt.colorbar()
```

`pcolor` has no attribute `zdir`, so you need to adjust the order of `xc,yc,fc` in the right way, depending on what you actually want to see.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but this is not what I am looking for. I'll explain better. If you try the example script from the matplotlib website, you will see that the ax.plot and the ax.scatter are plotted as projection on the 3d coordinates planes. I want to do this for the ax.pcolor as well (and not having it in a new figure like you suggest).