# 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

I can't get output from the following code in python at Zeppelin:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x = list(range(0, 100))
y = list(range(0, 100))
z = list(range(0, 100))

ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

And the error is:

> Fail to execute line 10: ax.scatter(x, y, z)
>
> AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'

In general, `scatter` does not work in python at Zeppelin and get the above error. Aslo, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37212257/3768871) does not work for me.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I just had to replace `pyplot.show()` by `plt.show()`

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks. this is not my problem. It was a typo. The error is on scatter.

Comment: You mean, `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` doesn't work either? It looks a lot like it's a problem with zeppelin then.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I mean the above code has the mentioned error. And error is on `as.Scatter`. So, what is the solution?

Answer (score -4):

A little bit late to answer...

You could try switching to Python x64 bit. Do not use x86 version. 
[image]
Remember to edit PATH priority of Python after installation. Also, you may need to verify by typing "python" in command line. 
[image]
This solution should work on 64 bit system only. Don't really know if the issue can happen on 32 bit or not.